# Netmeeting tool for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, software-rec, netmeeting

is there any free net meeting tool ( easy way ) tool is available for ubuntu ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/):

> Ekiga (formely known as GnomeMeeting)
>   is an open source VoIP and video
>   conferencing application for GNOME.
>   Ekiga uses both the H.323 and SIP
>   protocols. It supports many audio and
>   video codecs, and is interoperable
>   with other SIP compliant software and
>   also with Microsoft NetMeeting.

Comment: just for knowledge : is there any toll like this for windows ?

Comment: Well, **NetMeeting** is the tool I use in Windows XP (it comes with it). Ekigas advantage is that it is **interoperable** with NetMeeting; it's been discontinued in Vista, so Microsoft recommends other tools; you can read more on this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_NetMeeting

Comment: No .. I am asking about using  SIP

Answer (score 3):

You could run NetMeeting with [WINE on Ubuntu](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=659&iTestingId=28313) or,
use [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/index.php?rub=1) -- already referred by `alex` -- which is [a NetMeeting replacement](http://open-tube.com/ekiga-an-open-source-alternative-to-microsoft-netmeeting/) (has a Windows port).

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in ["Linux NETMEETING HOWTO"](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NetMeeting-HOWTO/index.html), which says:

> This document aims to describe how to
>   make Microsoft NetMeeting interoperate
>   with Linux

Comment: Good idea !!